# Chose coordinates where $g_{01}=g_{02}=g_{03}=0$ to disentangle space and time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

$g_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric tensor. It describes the curvature of spacetime in general relativity. The choice of coordinates is completely arbitrary. It should be possible to find and chose coordinates where $g_{01}=g_{02}=g_{03}=0$.

Then, only $g_{00}$ and the entries of g which are related to space, $g_{\mu\nu}$ with $\mu, \nu ={1,2,3}$ are not vanishing.

Are they special coordinates? Are some fancy characteristics visuable in those coordinates?

I'm thinking about the determinant $\sqrt{-g} $: If I'm doing a Laplace expansion it becomes easy to calculate with those coordinates as it is only

$|g| = g_{00} \cdot |g_{\mu\nu}|$

left, with $\mu, \nu ={1,2,3}$. And $|g_{\mu\nu}|$ then is only spatial.
Can I say that I disentangled space and time with that operation?
Can I read things like "if there's time dilation at one point of the universe, then there has to be volume increase as well" from that equation?
Furthermore, can that help to derive a metric out of a given stress-energy-momentum tensor? For example in the derivation of the Schwarzschild solution: Doesn't that lead to A=1/B instantaneously?

Comment: Yes, you can choose a coordinate system where the shift vector is zero. In general relativity, the lapse function $1/\sqrt{g^{00}}$ and the shift vector $g_{0i}$ are Lagrange multipliers of the Hamiltonian and Momentum constraints, respectively. See more [in the ADM formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism)

Comment: What does it mean for the metric coordinates to be completely arbitrary? I think your question has some $3+1$ split meaning, although I am not sure I understand the question. Isn't this what the decomposition of spacetime is about? Not sure what the time-dilation-gives-volumetric-increase aspect is, but I think that is what your question sounds like.

Comment: Unfortunately giving a physical meaning to coordinates really depends on the specific spacetime/metric you're working with. There isn't a one shoe fits all solution. Though as others have commented, you can look at the ADM decomposition to see if this is relevant to you.

Comment: I'm wondering whether I can write the Einstein field equations with those (special) coordinates and if we'll see sonething special.